# Grep a word in data header row in a tab-separated file, and cut that # column for every row

Tags: bash, csv, grep

```
no      de      en      fr      sv
eple    apfel   apple   pomme   äpple
kake    Kuchen  cake    gâteau  tårta
```

---

There are 20+ languages in each tab-separated dictionary file and they are ordered somehat randomly from file to file, so I'd like to figure out a solution to batch extract desired columns. I'd like to
grep desired language columns, and strip away all the language data I don't need.

I'd like to use grep, cut or other readily available Linux tools – anything's
fine as long as it gets the job done.

In my particular situation now I'd like to retrieve "no", "en" and "sv" columns.
So, I'd like my output file to ultimately look like:

```
no      en      sv
eple    apple   äpple
kake    cake    tårta
```

The same code should be applicable to data regardless of header row order, i.e. it may be "en fr sv de no" instead of the above "no de en fr sv" or any other variation.

Comment: As an aside, the language code for Swedish is `sv`, although it does get confused a lot with the country code `se`.

Comment: @triplee You're totally right, I didn't realize I'd made the mistake here. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -v FS='\t' -v OFS='\t' -v langs='no en se' '
# Collect the appropriate column numbers from the first row.
NR==1 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if (match(langs, "\\<"$i"\\>")) {
            col[i]++
        }
    }
}

{
    # Walk the columns and if this column number is in our list of columns print the value out.
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if (i in col) {
            printf "%s%s", $i, OFS
        }
    }
    print ""
}' file
```

If some entries run longer than eight letters the output from that might be off (column-wise) in which case piping that to `column -t -s $'\t'` might be of help.

Comment: This looks exactly like the kind of operations I had in mind! I'll try it later and then report back. A million thanks.

Comment: Ì tried piping it into column, but I believe I went wrong. Could you please update it for very long columns like "The apple didn't hang long."?

Comment: @EirikB. Can a column have spaces in it? Because that isn't going to work unless the input columns use something other than space as the delimiter. As to using column that *exact* pipeline should work on non-space-including data. Though it turns out you don't need `-s $'\t'` at all since there can't be other spaces. If there can be other spaces then you do need that but you also need other changes.

Comment: @Etan Reisner. There can be spaces, and any number of uncommon characters (Asian languages).

E.g. no&en languages: Dette er en setning.<tab>This is a sentence.

Basically I'm running it on a large dataset, can't predict what's in there, and it has to correspond to \t(.*?)\t

Comment: So the input file is tab delimited then? Having indicated that would have helped. Ah, I see it in the title but not the body.

Comment: @EirikB. Ok, updated to handle tab-delimited input. The `column` example from the post is still what you need.

Comment: @Etan Reisner. Works perfectly now, thanks a lot! Sorry about the messy instruction - I added tab-delimited in the query itself.